# partial differential equation applicational problem

Tags: physics, partial-derivative, mathematical-physics, applications

[image]

As a Maths student with not much knowledge in physics, I dont understand how the "string" can be "cut" into half at x=L/2. Also, how many initial conditions(data) does this question have apart from yt(x,0) = 0?

Comment: I would probably regard this as a limit of problems where the jump happens over smaller and smaller intervals.

Comment: @Ian thanks. Can you please elaborate your answer in a more tangible way as I have not much foundation in physics.

Comment: For instance you could think of the initial conditions where the function is piecewise linear between the four points $(0,0),(L/2-\delta,\alpha-\varepsilon),(L/2+\delta,-\alpha+\varepsilon),(L,0)$, where $\delta \to 0$ and $\varepsilon$ is chosen such that the first segment has slope $2 \alpha/L$ (so I guess $\varepsilon=2 \alpha \delta/L$). These are still not smooth, so you might want something smoother, but I think this is the idea.

Comment: @Ian So basically I can understand this as if the dotted line is part of the line but not two separate line, am i correct?

Comment: Not exactly, because then you don't have a function anymore. But as $\delta \to 0$, the function I wrote down converges to your function (in several senses, including pointwise everywhere except $L/2$).

Comment: I think I now get it. Can you explain how many initial conditions does this question have?

Comment: Still just two, it's just that one isn't a normal function.

Comment: @Ian I just found the solution to this question, yet it doesn't have much explanation on every steps. It says the first initial data is yt(x,0)=0, which I understand how this comes. The second condition is y(x,0)=2(alpha)/L for 0<x<L/2 and 2(alpha)(x-L)/L for L/2<x<L, where this part I find extremely confused.

Comment: That much is what is actually there: the given initial condition is not defined at $L/2$, but is defined elsewhere. It's still one function.

Comment: But how is the second condition being obtained? How do I know the equation of lines between x=0 to x=L/2 and x=L/2 to x=L?

Comment: ...That's just algebra, you know the points $(0,0)$ and $(L/2,\alpha)$ for the first line, and the points $(L/2,-\alpha)$ and $(L,0)$ for the second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22074/discussion-between-tommy-smith-and-ian).